Нужно ли двоеточие перед фразой?
Есть такое предложение: Разумеется, я много раз слышал фразы вроде «Женская сумка – портал в четвёртое измерение», однако карманы Макины скорее напоминали свалку. Или ещё один вариант: Он сказал мне что-то вроде «Пойдём гулять».
Часто встречаюсь с ситуацией, когда в предложении есть слово «вроде», после которого идёт фраза в кавычках. Нужно ли ставить двоеточие после него? Как мне кажется, паузы в речи после него особо не наблюдается.

Правильно:
Разумеется, я много раз слышал фразы вроде «Женская сумка – портал в четвёртое измерЕние», однако карманы Макины скорее напоминали свАлку.
Он сказал мне что-то вроде «Пойдём гулять».
Пояснение

В данном случае дословное высказывание является членом предложения, поэтому двоеточия и паузы нет.

Но на практике двоеточие иногда ставится и делается пауза, предупреждающая о пояснении, например:


Ты наверняка слышал фразы врОде (такой): «Деньги зарабатываются только тяжёлым трудом» или «К 25 годам ты обязательно должен задуматься о детях».
№ 278265. Здравствуйте! В последнее время часто слышу фразы вроде: "Те, кто сделали это".

А здесь в похожем предложении двоеточия
нет:

Все мы слышали фразы вроде «А ведь я предупреждал!» или «Ты что, не мог догадаться?» если не в свой адрес, то по крайней мере в адрес своих знакомых.

Обычно двоеточие ставится в конце предложения перед распространенной фразой. Если же предложение не заканчивается, то паузы нет и знак обычно не ставится.

ПРАВИЛА
Основное правило по этой теме изложено у Розенталя, где говорится о том, что дословные высказывания могут являться элементами предложения:
Примечание. Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится:
Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Г.);  
Он вспомнил пословицу «За двумя зайцами погонишься 
— ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от 
первоначального плана; 
Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова 
предложение, выражение, надпись и т. п., то перед 
ними ставится двоеточие: Мимо станции проносились 
скорые поезда с табличками на вагонах: «Москва — 
Владивосток».

Смежные темы
§ 15. Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения, где похожая ситуация, а именно авторский выбор двоеточия:
   3. Если однородным членам предложения не 
   предшествует обобщающее слово (словосочетание), 
   то перед ними двоеточие ставится только в том 
   случае, когда необходимо предупредить читателя, 
   что дальше следует перечисление: Из-под сена 
   виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и 
   ещё какие-то привлекательные узелки и коробочки 
   (Л. Т.); Тут были: Павел, чухонец, штабс-капитан 
   Ярошевич, фельдфебель Максименко, красная 
   фуражка, дама с белыми зубами, доктор (Ч.). 

О пояснительном двоеточии Розенталь также говорит в теме § 72. Вариативные знаки препинания  »»   Двоеточие — тире. Там выбор пояснительного двоеточия объясняется в БСП (значение какой именно? что именно?):
  5. Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных 
  сложных предложениях с пояснительными 
  отношениями: Авторов этих писем волновали разные 
  проблемы, но объединяло одно (: —) все они ждали 
  от газеты конкретной и действенной помощи; Всех 
  интересовал только один вопрос (: —) как поскорее 
  выпутаться из создавшегося положения; Я помню 
  пушок на его щеках (: —) он только начал бриться; 
  На голове её цветной платок (: —) по алому полю 
  зелёные розы; У меня правило (: —) никакого 
  кофепития перед сном.

